# Is it a common behaviour that an RTX card's GPU/memory idle clocks are high when using two 4K monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-rtx

I have two 4K monitors and one 1080p monitor, all of which are connected via DisplayPort. When using one monitor or when using one 4K monitor +  one 1080p monitor, the idle GPU/memory idle clocks, according to GPU-Z, are constantly 300 and 101 MHz, respectively and the board power draw is 22.5W. But if I use two 4K monitors, the idle clocks are constantly 1170 and 1750 MHz respectively and the board power draw is 43.5W.

Is this a common behaviour of most Nvidia RTX cards? To me, it seems a little bit strange because if the GPU could handle one 4K monitor (and additional one 1080p monitor) with 300MHz GPU and 101MHz GPU memory, why does it need 1170MHz GPU and 1750MHz GPU memory to handle two 4K monitors? It is not even linear... The RAM clock is 17 times higher.

Comment: I don’t experience this problem and I am running dual 4K displays